# How can I do a multithreading twisted python

Tags: python, multithreading, twisted, python-multithreading

I have a question that bothers me for a long time, currently I'm working on a daemon which operating requests from outside. Its like a server-client. In this project, I'm using a Twisted Python Framework, and I successful build a non-multithreading server, it works! But now, I need to serve several customers at once. I don't know how can I do this in Twisted Framework. I tried all what I know...

Please help me with this :|

```
class Server(protocol.Protocol, protocol.Factory):

def buildProtocol(self, addr):                               
    if addr.host in ipList:
        log.msg("Connected from IP: " + addr.host)
        return self
    return None

def dataReceived(self, data):
    reactor.callFromThread(self.actionCreator(data))

def actionCreator(self, data):
    jsonData = json.loads(data)
    if not jsonData["action"]:
        log.msg("Incorrect data from IP: " + self.transport.getPeer().host + " data: " + data)
        self.transport.write(json.dumps({'response' : '300'}))
    elif jsonData["action"] == 'echo':
        log.msg("Doing ask from IP: " + self.transport.getPeer().host)
        self.transport.write(json.dumps({'response' : '400', 'data' : {'status' : 'online'}}))
    elif jsonData["action"] == 'wget': 
        log.msg("Downloading file... for user - " + jsonData["user"])
        os.system("wget -q http://****************")
        self.transport.write(json.dumps({'response' : '400', 'data' : {'status' : 'downloaded'}}))
    else:
        log.msg("Incorrect data from IP: " + self.transport.getPeer().host + " data: " + data)
        self.transport.write(json.dumps({'response' : '300'}))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        log.msg("Running server...")
        context = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory(certificate + "/server.key", certificate + "/server.crt")
        log.msg("Initiating a secure SSL connection...")
        reactor.listenSSL(config.getint(general, 'port'), Server(), context)
        log.msg("Waiting for connections...")

        reactor.run()  
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server handles concurrent clients by default - without threads - as a property of the programming model followed by Twisted.

I don't see anything in your example code that invalidates this - if you remove the (broken) attempt to use threads this server shouldn't have any problem servicing more than one client.

Comment: So I dont need anything else for handle multiple clients in the same time?

Comment: So can You give me example how can I handle multiple clients at the same time? I know how Can I do this in Python but not in Twisted.

Comment: You already gave that example.  As I said in my answer, concurrent clients are supported by default.  If you're experiencing some problem that you think is related to *not* supporting concurrent clients, please describe that problem otherwise I can't tell you how to solve it.

Comment: Ok, I prepared a simple test and I think it will explain my problem. Of course for the first I run my Deamon (server), and next I launched 2 pages with 2 actions, both are wget inquiry, ( elif jsonData["action"] == 'wget': ). My problem is that the daemon, accepts and adopts the client connection, I do not know how to define, but it adds them to the queue "waiting" and supports client after client not for example 5 clients at the same time? At the current requirements, daemon must support several clients at the same time.

http://i42.tinypic.com/14ihlch.png

Comment: If you block the event loop then it stops handling events.  Don't use `os.system` to run `wget` - use `twisted.web.client` to make HTTP requests without blocking.  Look for other non-blocking APIs in Twisted for other tasks you might want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply, but I have the next question, You said that I shouldn't use os.system, but if I will must to use it for example to check the process status and next return this status to client, what then?